# Python properties best practice, a function inside a property

Tags: python, properties

Is it a good practice to have properties that are the result of very basic operations?
For example, let's say we have properties 'a' and 'b' and we can directly infer property 'c' from 'a' and 'b'. Is this considered bad coding style?

```
@property 
def c(self):
    return self.a + self.b
```

Thanks!

Comment: In general this seems ok to me. Omitting `def`, however, doesn't.

Comment: Yes you're right, of course. Added def :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One benefit of using a property, even for very simple calculations, is that the effective value of the property will be updated automatically if `a` or `b` changes.

For instance, if `c` were not a property, you'd have to update the value of `self.c` every time `self.a` or `self.b` changed:

```
self.a += 1
self.c = self.a + self.b
```

But if `c` is a property, you can simply write

```
self.a += 1
self.c  # will already have the updated value
```

Comment: How about statements like asking whether an object is empty (let's say defined via its length), i.e.
`def is_empty(self): return len(self)==0`

What is the preferred way to do it here? As a function or as a property?

Comment: That's a matter of style, but I would look to the standard library for guidance on what to do here. `Lists` do not have an `is_empty` method (neither function nor property). To test if a `list` is non-empty, you just write `if seq`. Your class will behave the same way if the `__len__` method is defined. Your class seems to already have `__len__` defined since you are using `len(self)`. So I would recommend not having an `is_empty` function or property, and just using `if not self` instead of `self.is_empty`.

Comment: @SmCaterpillar It's a meter of taste, but both ways are fine. The important thing is that you encapsulated a functionality. Is it a function or property, it really doesn't meter that much.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context. If you have a `start_time` and `end_time` property and you want the `duration` it makes sense to create a property. I other cases it may or may not be appropriate. But it's not considered a bad coding style.